# Updating a single value in a dictionary in firebase - Swift project

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, firebase

I'm working on iOS application using swift and firebase. 
I'm trying to let the user change his email and password and the rest of his information stored in firebase in the same view controller using separate buttons.

Here's example of one user from the dashboard:

```
    {
     "Users" : {
       "08e5443c-cdde-4fda-8733-8c4fce75dd34" : {
         "BusinessName" : "looliCake",
         "Category" : "Cooking",
         "City" : "Riyadh",
         "ContactMe" : "05551233210",
         "Details" : "many flaiver choose",
         "Email" : "loolicack@gmail.com",
         "PhoneNumber" : "05551233210",
         "Provider" : "123",
         "ShortDescription" : "best pop cake ever . ",
         "Website1" : "www.looliCack.com",
         "Website2" : "https://www.instagram.com/loolicack/"
        }
      }
    }
```

Here's the code:

```
let mainpass = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("password") as? String
let mainEmail = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Email") as? String



@IBAction func EditEmail(sender: AnyObject) {

    if EmailAddressTF.text==""
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message:"Make sure to fill in all required textfields", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in })
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){}
    }
    else
    {
        let isEqu = (mainEmail == self.EmailAddressTF.text)
        if(isEqu == true) {

        } else {
            let ref = Firebase(url: "https://businesswallet.firebaseio.com/")

            ref.changeEmailForUser(mainEmail, password: mainpass, toNewEmail: self.EmailAddressTF.text, withCompletionBlock: { error in

                if error != nil {

                    if let errorCode = FAuthenticationError(rawValue: error.code) {

                        switch (errorCode) {
                        case .EmailTaken:
                            print("Email taken")
                            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message:"Sorry,Email taken", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in })
                            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){}

                        case .InvalidEmail:
                            print("invalid email")
                            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message:"invalid email", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in })
                            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){}


                        case .NetworkError:
                            print("Network Error")
                            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message:"Network error, check your connection", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in })
                            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){}

                        default:
                            print("Unknown Error")
                            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message:"Unknown Error", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in })
                            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){}
                        }
                    }





                } else {

                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(self.EmailAddressTF.text, forKey: "Email")
                    print("Email changed successfully")

                    let newUser = [
                        "Provider": self.PasswordTF.text!,
                        "Email": self.EmailAddressTF.text,
                        "BusinessName": self.BusinessNameTF.text ,
                        "ShortDescription" : self.ShortDescriptionTF.text,
                        "Category" : self.itemSelected,
                        "City" : self.CityTF.text,
                        "ContactMe" : self.ContactMeTF.text,
                        "PhoneNumber" : self.PhoneNumberTF.text,
                        "Website1": self.Website1TF.text,
                        "Website2": self.Website2TF.text,
                        "Details": self.DetailsTV.text
                    ]


                    self.ref.childByAppendingPath("Users").childByAppendingPath(self.ref.authData.uid).updateChildValues(newUser)
                    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

                }

            })

        } //Big Else


    }



} //EditEmailButton




@IBAction func EditPassword(sender: AnyObject) {

    if  PasswordTF.text==""
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message:"Make sure to fill in all required textfields", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in })
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){}
    }
    else
    {
        if RepasswordTF.text != PasswordTF.text
        {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message:"You Entered Different Passwords", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in })
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){}
        }
        else {


            ref.changePasswordForUser( NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Email") as? String, fromOld: NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("password") as? String, toNew: self.PasswordTF.text)
            {

                (ErrorType) -> Void in
                if ErrorType != nil {
                    print(ErrorType)
                    print("There was an error processing the request")
                }
                else
                {

                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(self.PasswordTF.text, forKey: "password")
                    print("Password changed successfully")

                }

            }


            let newUser = [
                "Provider": self.PasswordTF.text!,
                "Email": self.EmailAddressTF.text,
                "BusinessName": self.BusinessNameTF.text ,
                "ShortDescription" : self.ShortDescriptionTF.text,
                "Category" : self.itemSelected,
                "City" : self.CityTF.text,
                "ContactMe" : self.ContactMeTF.text,
                "PhoneNumber" : self.PhoneNumberTF.text,
                "Website1": self.Website1TF.text,
                "Website2": self.Website2TF.text,
                "Details": self.DetailsTV.text
            ]


            self.ref.childByAppendingPath("Users").childByAppendingPath(self.ref.authData.uid).updateChildValues(newUser)
            self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

        }


    } //else


}



@IBAction func EditBusinessInfo(sender: AnyObject) {

    if BusinessNameTF.text==""
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message:"Make sure to fill in all required textfields", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in })
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){}
    }
    else
    {

        let newUser = [
            "Provider": self.PasswordTF.text!,
            "Email": self.EmailAddressTF.text,
            "BusinessName": self.BusinessNameTF.text ,
            "ShortDescription" : self.ShortDescriptionTF.text,
            "Category" : self.itemSelected,
            "City" : self.CityTF.text,
            "ContactMe" : self.ContactMeTF.text,
            "PhoneNumber" : self.PhoneNumberTF.text,
            "Website1": self.Website1TF.text,
            "Website2": self.Website2TF.text,
            "Details": self.DetailsTV.text
        ]


        self.ref.childByAppendingPath("Users").childByAppendingPath(self.ref.authData.uid).updateChildValues(newUser)
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

    }
}
```

In each button, I'm updating the entire dictionary in firebase! Which's wrong!

How can I update in firebase only the email value in email button,
and provider in password button?

Comment: I did solve the problem by adding:   self.ref.childByAppendingPath("Users").childByAppendingPath(self.ref.authData.uid).updateChildValues(["Email":self.EmailAddressTF.text!]) in email button instead of the dictionary.

Comment: And adding:    self.ref.childByAppendingPath("Users").childByAppendingPath(self.ref.authData.uid).updateChildValues(["Provider":self.PasswordTF.text!]) in passsword button instead of the dictionary.

Answer (score 29):

This question and answer in the comments helped me out. Since there isn't an official answered question, I will add one with updated code cause the one in the comments is deprecated.

```
ref.child("yourKey").child("yourKey").updateChildValues(["yourKey": yourValue])
```

This worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Great! Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

you can simply navigate to that single value which you want to update then use setValue(and here give it the value)
here is a very simple example :

```
var key : FIRDatabaseReference!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    addData()
}



func addData()
{

    var data :Dictionary<String,Any> = ["name":"nawal","id":123]
   key =  DBprovider.instance.DBRef.child("Data").childByAutoId()
    key.setValue(data)

}
```

//add a button name it update or whatEver and connect it as Action

```
@IBAction func updateData(_ sender: Any) {

    DBprovider.instance.DBRef.child("Data").child(key.key).child("id").setValue(111)


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  let path1 = FirebaseBaseUrl + "users/" + id
            let chilRef1 = FIRDatabase.database().referenceFromURL(path1)
            // chilRef1.updateChildValues(["status": "online"])

            chilRef1.updateChildValues(["status": "offline"]) { (error, ref) in
                if(error != nil){
                    print("Error",error)
                }else{
                    print("\n\n\n\n\nYou are Offline...")
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is working in swift 4 and 5

```
func updateAnyFirebaseVale(_ param :  String){

    if let id = self.currentId{

        let val =  Database.database().reference(fromURL:
            "Your_URL").child("CHILD NODE NAME").child("ID YOU WANT TO UPDATE ")

        val.updateChildValues(["specific param name to update like password name etc" : "value of param"])

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Message Header", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default, handler: { (alert) in


        }))

        self.present(alert,animated: true)

}
```