# Firebase Data Retrieval - Edit Annotation

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, annotations, firebase-authentication

I am currently working on an application where the users can save an annotation on their map and this all works great! The map location, name and subtitle are all sent to the database and the pin is put into the map.

However, I am struggling to figure out how to pull this data back down from [Firebase][1] so the users are able to edit the previous information and then update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read data, you want to use the [observe](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write) attribute from your firebase reference. This returns a `snapshot` consisting of your data.

Since your `Skatepark` class already has a snapshot constructor, all you'd have to do is pass the snapshot to it and create your object.

```
reference.child("yourNode").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

/* Two things can happen here. Snapshot can either consist of one element or multiple.
   To handle this, you want to iterate through the snapshot, create your Skatepark
   object and populate it into your global skatepark array.
*/

    if snapshot.value is NSNull
    {
        print("Error Getting Snapshot")
    }
    else
    {
        for (child in snapshot.children)
        {
            let snap = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
            let skateObject = Skatepark(child) // this calls the constructor which take snapshot as parameter
            globalSkateParkArray.append(skateObject)
        }
    }

})
```

To update your values, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39754975/4962554) is all you need.

**Personal Recommendations**

1. Consider making `coordinate`, `name`, `subtitle` into `var` instead of `let`.
2. Consider creating a `Skatepark` object first out of the data before sending it to the database. This constructor should do the trick

   ```
   init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, name: String, subtitle: String, type: SkateboardType, editable: Bool)
   {
       self.coordinate = coordinate
       self.name = name
       self.subtitle = subtitle
       self.type = type
       self.editable = editable
   }
   ```
3. I'd create a `dictionary` variable inside `Skatepark` that creates a dictionary from the object. This way I won't have `["lat": locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude, "lng": locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude, "name": skateTitleText, "subtitle": skateStyleText, "type": (selected - 1), "editable": true]` floating all around my codebase.

So have this in your class

```
var dictionary: [String:Any]
{
    return
    [
        "lat": coordinate.latitude,
        "lng": coordinate.longitude,
        "name": title,
        "subtitle": subtitle,
        "type": type,
        "editable": editable
    ]
}
```

Every time you'd want a dictionary out of your object, simply use `object.dictionary`

Comment: Which part is confusing exactly?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what to change this line of code too after putting the dictionary in my class?

 locationsRef.setValue(["lat": locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude, "lng": locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude, "name": skateTitleText, "subtitle": skateStyleText, "type": (selected - 1), "editable": true])

Comment: So one thing that I noticed is that you have a well defined class structure but you're not really fully utilizing it. This is one instance of that problem. You first want to create an object, before sending it off to Firebase. The same applies with when you retrieve stuff from Firebase.

Comment: Object creation: `let park = Skatepark(locationManager.location?.coordinate, skateTitleText, skateStyleText, (selected - 1), editable)`. Then simply do `locationsRef.setValue(park.dictionary)`

Comment: Okay, I have added an edit in my post above. Is this how my class should look now?

Comment: Yes, that looks correct. Now refer back to my updated answer to see how to grab all the data. I'd recommend first commenting out all the code inside the else portion and simply type `print(snapshot.value)` to see the structure of the data. Then uncomment the for loop and eventually print out `skateObject` to see what the object looks like. Afterwards, tackle the update issue.

Comment: @Aviato Don't forget to upvote and accept as answer since it resolves your issue.

Comment: I still dont understand what I am meant to change this too? Ref.setValue(["lat": locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude, "lng": locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude, "name": skateTitleText, "subtitle": skateStyleText, "type": (selected - 1), "editable": true])

Comment: I did already. Its in the 4th comment. You first want to create an object to hold the entered data, its called `park`. Thereafter, simply pass `park.dictionary` into your `setValue` function.

Comment: I think I understand I am just having an issue with editable? I have update the code above. The issue is use of unresolved identifier editable

Comment: Buddy, I sent you the generic solution. You need to adapt it to your codebase. By defining `let park = Skatepark(locationManager.location?.coordinate, skateTitleText, skateStyleText, (selected - 1), editable)`, _editable_ is supposed to be a boolean variable. In your original code, you set it to `true` by default. Just do the same. `let park = Skatepark(locationManager.location?.coordinate, skateTitleText, skateStyleText, (selected - 1), true)`

Comment: Okay sorry I am just confused and don't understand some of these things as I am fairly new, like the locationManager not working, but thats fine and  thanks for you help, I appreciate it

Comment: Its fine buddy. No worries. Unless otherwise, most answers tend to be generic in SO so you still have to find some workarounds. Regarding your `locationManager` issue look at [this](http://rshankar.com/get-your-current-address-in-swift/) to understand how it works then go back to your code and check. If it still persists, look around SO for a similar question. If nothing, post a new question.
_Sidenote:_ When I made location-based apps, I had issues whenever I'd run it on the simulator. Try running on an actual device if you're currently not.

Comment: How does this help me pull down data from Firebase into my text fields though?

Comment: I'd recommend you Google around how to do that. I have no idea how many of them you have and since you're storing the result in an array, then you'd possibly have to create multiple textfields?! For simplicity's sake, add `self.skateTitleText.text = globalSkateParkArray[0]` right after the for loop. Thereafter figure out how to get it to work for all the elements in the array.