# Facebook SDK and Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, firebase, uilabel

I want to retrieve user's data from `Facebook` and store that particular data in `firebase` and display it on `UILabel`

Please provide any helpful link if there's any.

**My Code:**

```
  fileprivate  func setupFacebookButton() {

        // add facebook button
        let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()

        loginButton.frame = CGRect(x: 24, y:  535, width: 165, height: 44)
        loginButton.delegate = self
        loginButton.readPermissions = ["email", "public_profile" , "user_birthday", "user_location"]
        view.addSubview(loginButton)
    }
```

and

```
let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.current()
guard let accessTokenString = accessToken?.tokenString else { return }
let credentials = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: accessTokenString)
Auth.auth().signIn(with: credentials, completion: { (user, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("Something went wrong with our FB user: ", error ?? "")
        return
    }

    print("Successfully logged in with our user: ", user ?? "")
})
let requestParameters =  ["fields": "name, email, birthday, gender, location"]


//location first_name, gender, age_range, user_birthday
FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: requestParameters).start { (connection, result, err) in
    if err != nil {
            print("Failed to start graph request:", err ?? "")
            return
        }
print(result ?? "")
    }
```

**Output**:

```
{
    birthday = "09/21/1987";
    email = "user@mail.ru";
    gender = male;
    id = 1520497814669566;
    location =     {
        id = 106065422766757;
        name = "User city, User Country";
    };
    name = "User Name";
}
Successfully logged in with our user:  <FIRUser: 0x6080000c87a0>
```

Comment: What info from Facebook are u trying to store? Is it the entire `result` or just certain data?

Comment: @EmilDavid only the entire result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to do the whole thing for you but instead give you hints and pointers.

Judging from your question, you don't seem to have Firebase setup yet. Before you continue reading, go ahead and follow [these](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup) steps beforehand and check out their examples to understand how to structure your database.

**1. Class Creation**

I'd encapsulate all this data into a class called `Person` as shown below.

```
struct Location
{
    var id: Int = ''
    var name: String = ''
}

class Person
{
    var id: Int = 0
    var name: String = ''
    var email: String = ''
    var gender: String = ''
    var birthday: String = ''
    var location: Location = Location()

    init(id: Int, name: String, email: String, gender: String, birthday: String, location: Location)
    {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.gender = gender
        self.birthday = birthday
        self.location = location
    }

    // TODO: Finish implementing this
    init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot)
    {
        // This will make it easier to creating objects once you retrieve data from Firebase
    }

    // TODO: Finish implementing this
    var dictionary: [String:Any]
    {
        return
        [
            // This will make it easier to create a dictionary out of your object
        ]
    }
}
```

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39934730/4962554) question and see how they implemented their `init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot)` constructor and try implementing yours. Its important that you look at how their database tree looks like first for it to make sense.

For the `var dictionary` part, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44029155/4962554) answer will surely help you implement yours.

**2. Facebook Result Understanding**

Just like most APIs out there, Facebook queries return JSON. JSON is just a key/value pairing which means they can be stored as dictionaries.

I'd recommend you first try fiddling around with `result` in order to understand it.

To extract say the username, you'd've to do `let userName = result.valueForKey("name") as! String`.

***Be careful with the casting. I am casting it to a `String` because from the result, it is a `String`. For `id`, you'd've to cast to an `Int` instead***.

If you look at `location` though, it consists of another dictionary inside it. I'll let u figure out how to extract the info from there.

**3. Firebase**

Hopefully by the time you are here you're familiar with read/write in Firebase.
As you might have noticed, in order to save data to Firebase you need to give it a dictionary. This is were the `var dictionary` variable comes into play. Read the answer and comments to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44028023/firebase-data-retrieval-edit-annotation) question to understand how to use it and its relevancy.

**4. Summary**

Once you've followed all of the above steps, it's time to piece them together.

- Extract contents from Facebook
- Create a `Person` object out of it
- Pass `object.dictionary` into the write function of Firebase.
- *VOILA!* Watch your database populate; this is the most important part :)

Happy coding. Cheers mate :)

Comment: Thank u very much !

Comment: @FaigHuseynov You're welcomed. Please accept as answer if it helped resolve your problem and also to allow for the question to be closed on SO

Comment: This method is suitable for uisegmentcontrol? Using a segment, I define the gender (male/female)

Comment: Yes it is.. Just use `selectedSegmentIndex` property to get the currently selected segment then assign its value to the object's `age`. The main idea of using classes is that they are versatile. As long as you have data, they can be used anywhere